# Get Associated Foreign key from Combo Box c#

Tags: c#

How can I get Foreign Key using Combo box value member.

```
private void cmbTeacher_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TeacherID = this.cmbTeacher.ValueMember;
    txtReferBy.Text = cmbTeacher.GetItemText(cmbTeacher.ValueMember);
}
```

it is showing 2 every time even when I change the selected item from combobox

Comment: I'm guessing this is a WPF project, so please add relevant XAML code also

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.